# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nunique'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am getting the error below after running the code at end. Please let me know how to solve it. I am importing pandas, numpy before.

```
 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nunique'

train_dt = pd.DataFrame(train.dtypes,columns = ['Numpy Dtype'])
train_dt['Nunique'] = train.nunique()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to upgrade pandas because [`DataFrame.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) is implemented in `pandas 0.20.0`:

> DataFrame.nunique(axis=0, dropna=True)
>   Return Series with number of distinct observations over requested axis.
>   New in version 0.20.0.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you write your line code true
Example:

True way:

```
    `datafram.groupby('column')['column'].nunique()` #this is true way
```

wrong way:

```
    `datafram.groupby('column'),['column'].nunique()` #this way give you your error
```